# Flagging an Answer if all (or most) comments should be deleted

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

From [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) page:

> If you see a post where many comments should be deleted, especially if there's an ongoing discussion, there’s no need to flag each comment. Flag the post for moderator attention, and use the “other” reason explain what's going on.

I recently flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator/394814#394814) with the reason "*None of these comments add anything useful to the answer*", but this was denied with:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Is the advice to flag a post somehow no longer valid (since I don't think than a moderator found these 22 comments useful, what little information they contain, is also in the answer)?

I previously always flagged one comment, and mentioned in the description that more comments should be deleted, and that I flagged only one comments.

Comment: I find there were some argumentations on the comment thread, and some upvoted ones. Big chance mods didn't see them as "not useful"

Comment: @Sompuperoo Also, according to the help: "*obsolete — a comment that is no longer relevant because it has been addressed by an edit to the post, clarified by additional comments, or contains no context because it references deleted content*" ... Which is the case here... Most of the other comments are just a discussion on which syntax is better, and don't really add anything IMHO (the upvotes here probably reflect agree/disagree here)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 26 comments on that answer; we have two (practical) options:

- Delete all 26 comments
- Do nothing.

We *could* go through and manually pick which comments to keep and which comments to purge, but is that really a good use of moderator time?

Your best bet when there are a lot of comments where some are highly upvoted and some are not is to flag each comment that you believe should be deleted. We do not always have subject matter expertise on answers, and so we generally default to delete all comments or keep all comments when those sorts of flags are left.

In this case, you got the latter, and it resulted in a declination.

The issue with the text of your flag is that you don't inform the moderator that you've gone ahead and added the relevant information from the comments to the answer. That's really important information and is the difference between "There might be trash over there, clean it up" and "I cleaned up everything I could, but I hear you have a more powerful tool to clean up trash with. Could you clean up the rest for me?"

If you do edit the information from the comments into the answer, *lead with that*. A flag like "I edited all the relevant information from the comments to the answer, the comment thread can now be purged without losing any information." Would be a great flag as it tells us:

- What you've done
- Why we need to intervene
- What you need us to do

Comment: This is a valid point, but this is also true for users (ie. me); I ended up on that question through an internet search, and had to go through 26 comments to see if there was some useful information which supplemented the answer; to prevent the next user from having to do the same, I edited the answer to include the useful information that there was, and considered all comments to be "worthy of deletion" ... I think that *especially* with frequent questions like this, removing these comments is a useful thing to do. In this particular example, *even* the highly upvoted comments add very little

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The issue with the text of your flag is that you don't inform the moderator that you've gone ahead and added the relevant information from the comments to the answer.  That's really important information and is the difference between "There might be trash over there, clean it up" and "I cleaned up everything I could, but I hear you have a more powerful tool to clean up trash with. Could you clean up the rest for me?"

Comment: Thank you. You're right, my summary that I gave was crap.